# Extracting Variables out of .swf using c++

Tags: c++, flash, reverse-engineering, bytecode

I am currently working on a project which relies on variables and constants defined in an external .swf-File. As I don't have the sourcecode to the .swf file I need to extract the content of these variables by decompiling and copy&pasting the variables by hand. I was wondering if there is a way to extract these variables by analysing the bytecode using c++ for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be written in C but, after doing some quick googling this project seems to be the closet match to what you're looking for:

http://openswf.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/openswf/

If that doesn't work for you, you can always check out the SWF file specification (fully documented) [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/swf.html) and write up your own parser like a boss. ;)

Comment: My boss doesn't write parsers; he gets me to write them.  I like the expression though.  +1